# Creating a client server program across local network only

Tags: c#, .net, tcp, client-server, offline

Basically I need to create a client and server using only the local network, there won't be a connection to the internet. Would using TcpClient suffice, or does that need an internet connection?

Comment: What language / framework are you referring to? Typically you don't need access to the Internet for network applications, you do need a network connection and _may_ need access to a DNS server.

Comment: C# .net framework. From what I have been told there will be a network connection between the two. I am assuming using TcpClient with the local ip address' will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Would using TcpClient suffice, or does that need an internet
>   connection?

No, you don't need an internet connection. All you need is a `hub` or a `router` that can direct the IP packets to all the computers inside the local network.